# Losing my data when i refresh page in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a social network for project in my formation, i have a like system and it work.

i have a components cardArticle with all info and i try to do a like count. It work but when i refresh the page or going on other page, i lost all my data likes (my data is not saved)

components/CardArticle.vue

```
    <template>
  <div id="card">
    <div>
      <a class="cardLink">
        <img class="card-img" v-if="post.imageUrl !== undefined" :src="post.imageUrl" />
        <h2 class="cardTitle"> {{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="cardDescription"> {{ post.description }}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonIcon">
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="buttonDelete" id="buttonDelete" @click="deletePost"
          v-if="this.post.userId === this.user.userId || this.user.isAdmin === true">Supprimer</button>
        <button type="button" class="buttonEdit" id="buttonEdit" @click="modifyPost"
          v-if="this.post.userId === this.user.userId || this.user.isAdmin === true">
          Editer
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="divIconLike">
        <div class="iconLike">
          <a @click="sendLike">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="countLike">
          <p> {{ likes }} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import router from "../router/index.js";


export default {
  name: 'CardArticle',
  data () {
    return {
      likes: 0
    }
  },
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.getters.user;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendLike() {
      axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/articles/" + this.post._id + "/like", {
        userId: this.user.userId
      }, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.user.token
        }
      })
        .then(response => this.likes = response.data.article.likes)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

views/home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home" v-if="this.user.token !== null">
    <CardArticle v-for="post in allPosts" v-bind:key="post.id" :post="post" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CardArticle from "../components/CardArticle.vue"
import axios from "axios";


export default {
  name: 'HomeArticle',
  data () {
    return {
      post: {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        imageUrl: ""
      },
      allPosts: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.getters.user;
    }
  },
  components: {
    CardArticle,
},
  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/articles", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.user.token
        }
      })
        .then(response => { 
          this.allPosts = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return error;
        })
  }
}

</script>
```

What i should do for not losing my data ?
I would not use vuex or localstorage for that if possible, you have idea ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you loading data from server, then refresh page, you always will be lose data, because browser loading page again from server, and application will load data again.

If you don't want use `vuex` (but why not?), you can write data to `cookies` (by setting cookie value), then load it on app startup (when page is loaded). But it's not best practice at all. You can use `vue3-cookies` lib ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-cookies)).

By the way, better learn to use stores, most progressive, I think, is `Pinia`.

Check: https://pinia.vuejs.org/

Comment: Hi, I use pinia here, but if I refresh the page, data is not showing after it has been loaded into store. This should be reactive, so why it's not refreshing, eg. filling the data? https://talentexploit.com/matchRates

Comment: @Dgloria are you preloading data on page first load? Also, you can write a getter which loads data (with pinia action) from server if  pinia state is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> i lost all my data likes (my data is not saved)

`likes` is belong to each articles and It should have been saved to your **db** and call API to retrieve it again on component mounting:

```js
export default {
  name: 'CardArticle',
  data () {
    return {
      likes: 0   // It's not managed by component state
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendLike() {
      axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/articles/" + this.post._id + "/like", {
        userId: this.user.userId
      }, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.user.token
        }
      })
        .then(
          // invalidates, update allPosts props (emit to parent)
        )
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, it work perfectly :)
I create a get route in my back and create mounted with axios.get where i define this.likes.